# Computing half vector on WebGL

Tags: webgl

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/index.php?ogldir2 shows the following:

> H = Eye - L

I did the following on my WebGL vertex shader to compute the half-vector:

```
vec4 ecPosition = u_mvMatrix * vec4(a_position.xyz, 1.0); // Get the eye coordinate position
vec3 eyeDirection = normalize(-ecPosition.xyz);           // Get the eye direction
v_halfVector = normalize(eyeDirection + lightDirection);  // Compute and normalize the half-vector
```

But I am not sure if the above code snippets are correct.

Any pointer/help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: It seems the correct code should be

```
vec4 ecPosition = u_mvMatrix * vec4(a_position.xyz, 1.0); // Position in the eye coordinate position
vec3 ecLightPosition = (u_mvMatrix * lightPosition).xyz;  // Light position in the eye coordinate
vec3 lightDirection = ecLightPosition - ecPosition.xyz    // Light direction
vec3 eyeDirection = (-ecPosition.xyz);                    // Eye direction
v_halfVector = normalize(eyeDirection + lightDirection);  // Compute and normalize the half-vector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to get the average of the eye and light vectors, shouldn't that last line be "normalize(eyeDirection + lightDirection)" instead? Also, it might make more sense to invert the light vector instead of the eye since it's coming out of the surface.

I'm not an expert here, so take my advice with a huge grain of salt. :)